# $ \Bbb Q [ \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} ] = \Bbb Q [ \sqrt{2} , \sqrt{3} ] $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove, that
$ \Bbb Q [ \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} ] = \Bbb Q [  \sqrt{2} , \sqrt{3} ]  $

I don't know the definition of 
$\Bbb Q [  \sqrt{2} , \sqrt{3} ]$, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_%28field_theory%29

Comment: @nik To a student just learning the basics of field theory, I'd say they're fundamentally different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have : $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)=\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3]$ because $\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3$ are algebraic over $\mathbb Q$

$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$ this is the smallest field containing $\mathbb Q,$ $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$

Since  $\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3) $ we have $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)\subset\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$ then it suffice to prove that $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3):\mathbb Q]=[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3):\mathbb Q],$ as $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3):\mathbb Q]=[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3):\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)][\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2):\mathbb Q]$  we have $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3):\mathbb Q]=4$ (because Irr($\sqrt 3$,$\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2))=X^2-3.$) you can easily check by calculating that : deg(Irr($\sqrt 3+\sqrt 2$,$\mathbb Q)$=4

so $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2+\sqrt 3)$

Comment: The question was about $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ - which is not a field directly from the definitions. It's nontrivial that $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha] = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Comment: @Mike because $\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3$ algebraic over $\mathbb Q$

Comment: I know why it's true. But to a student who's just seen these for the first time, they're different, and the question he's looking to answer likely wants him to explicitly show that they're the same (by showing they have the same elements).