# Is it obvious that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)$?

Tags: field-theory

Is it obvious that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)$ ? If not how can I show it ?

Comment: Thisis a well-known question on this site - see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93463/is-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3). Replace $2$ and $3$ by $3$ and $5$. See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598262/bbb-q-sqrt2-sqrt3-bbb-q-sqrt2-sqrt3?lq=1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first inclusion is obvious because $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$
 is closed under addition. So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}  +\sqrt{5}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}  ,\sqrt{5})$.

To second inclusion observe that
$$(\sqrt{3}  +\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{3}  -\sqrt{5}) = 3 - 5 = -2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{5}  -\sqrt{3} = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{5}  +\sqrt{3}}$$

then $\sqrt{5}  -\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}  +\sqrt{5})$. Now use sum and subtraction to find that $\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}  +\sqrt{5})$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: @DietrichBurde We got it man, what is it?I didn't see that answer. This is pattern. Why the downvote?

Comment: Whatever, no reason for the downvote though.

Answer (score 4):

It is obvious if the facts below are obvious:

- $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)$ has degree 4
- $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5)$ has degree 4
- $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5) \subseteq \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)$

Of these, only the last one is *really* obvious.

Comment: Your comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93463/is-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3-mathbfq-sqrt2-sqrt3) is already a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

$(\sqrt3+\sqrt 5)^2\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt  5)$

$\implies 8+2\sqrt3.\sqrt 5\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt  5)$

$\implies \sqrt3.\sqrt 5\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt  5)$

$\implies (\sqrt3+\sqrt 5).\sqrt3.\sqrt 5\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt  5)$

$\implies 3\sqrt 5+5\sqrt3\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt  5)$

$3(\sqrt3+\sqrt 5)\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt  5)$

$\implies 2\sqrt 3\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt  5)$

$\implies \sqrt 3\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt  5)$

similarly $\sqrt 5\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt  5)$

Thus $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt  5)\subseteq \mathbb Q(\sqrt3,\sqrt5)$

The other part is obvious

Comment: I'm sure you meant to have the inclusion in the next to last line going in the other direction.  You have indeed tackled the nonobvious half of the problem.